# VB.NET ADODB Recorset Contar rows por cada filtro

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net

Tengo un query al ejecutarla me trae una cierta cantidad de datos, pero como pueden ver en el where lleva dos variables, como puedo contar cuantas son de uno variable y cuantas de la otra:

```html
RSMAster.Open("SELECT *  FROM Frecuencias where frecuencia  in ('4','2')", Connsql, CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)
```

Uitlizando *RSMAster.RecordCount* puedo contar todos los rows pero no cada uno por ejemplo quiero contar cuantos son de 4 y cuantos son de 2, como le haria?

Answer (score 0):

Agupa tu query por ese campo, y has un count sobre el mismo

```
select frecuencia, count(frecuencia)
from Frecuencias 
where frecuencia  in ('4','2')
```

Comment: lo que pasa que utilizo todos los datos que me trae el query siempre al menos me trae 1000 o 1500 datos y lo que tu mencionas solo traeria 2 rows

Comment: y en tu pregunta, donde esta especificado eso?

Comment: al final de la pregunta se especifica

Comment: Esta query te da la cuenta de cuantos son de 4 y cuantos son de 2.. no entiendo tu problema.. vos queres ademas tener todos los datos?

Comment: asi es, el query principal select * y contar cuantos de cada uno(4 y 2) en el mismo query

Comment: @Manny podrias mostrar como queres tu salida entonces? en cual de las 1000 filas vas a mostrar eso?